# Ubuntu Live Session Installation Problem

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, live-cd

1. Problem: Can’t install a live session of Ubuntu 18.04.3
2. What I’ve done:

a.  Downloaded the install program twice and burned it twice to 2 different DVDs with disk verification.

b.  Allowed both disks to boot from the computer’s DVD.  “Ubuntu 18.4” appears on the screen with 5 moving activity dots.  After several minutes, the program stops loading and dumps a page of line commands onto the black screen, the last line being “Good signature Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signature Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com”.  Within about 2 minutes the computer just reboots on its own.

c. Alternately, I hit any key when the CD starts loading, go to the language page, then to the page with “Try Ubuntu without installing”, “Install Ubuntu”, “Check Disk for Defects”, etc.  Pressing the first option, it begins to load for several minutes, the screen goes black, and the computer reboots.

d.  With “c” above under “F6” on the Ubuntu menu screen, I’ve checked “nomodeset”.  The program boots first in low resolution “Ubuntu” type face for several minutes, goes to a black screen, and the computer reboots.

e.  With “c” above under “F1/F7”, I’ve tried “aic7xxx.aic7xxx=no-probe” for “special Dell computers” in the line command but don’t know if I’m using the right syntax, and/or don’t understand the instructions.

f.  With “c” above, I’ve checked all options under “F6”.  Loads for a while, goes to black screen, and reboots.

g. I tried “Check Disk for Defects” but the computer just reboots after a time, telling me nothing about the disk.

3. As an aside, when trying to install a live session of “Mint Cinamon”, the computer reaches a desktop, but after about 2 minutes of activity opening programs or absolutely no activity on my part, the computer will just reboot on its own.
4. Hardware:  Dell Precision 3420 Tower running on Windows 7 Professional (64-bit), Intel Quad Core I5-6600 Processor, 8 GB RAM (4x2 slots), Nvidia Quadro K420 video card (2GB) with unused Intel onboard video card (disabled in Windows, can’t disable it in the BIOS), RAID1 with two 500GB SATA hard drives, Intel NIC card and unused onboard Intel NIC, onboard Realtek sound card, wireless Logitec M510 mouse, wired Dell keyboard, DVD-burner, Dell 24” monitor. Computer new as of 02/2017 with no current problems on Windows 7. BIOS up-to-date:  “Legacy” enabled, “Legacy Option ROM” enabled, “Secure Reboot” disabled, UEFI can only be enabled if “Legacy” is disabled.  I use Firefox, Thunderbird, and Libre on Windows 7.

Can someone please help me get at least a live session out of Ubuntu so I can see what the program is? Eventually I will want to duel-boot it with Windows 7, since I have programs like Adobe “After Effects” and “Photoshop”, along with Autodesk “AutoCad” in Windows. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect that you have problems with the graphics or with the settings for the internal disk, but there might be other problems too. Linux (including Ubuntu) wants the setting AHCI (while Windows is probably using something else (maybe a RAID setup). This should be changed in a BIOS settings menu. -- A two year old Dell should work. I have an nvidia Quadro K4000 card and it works well with Ubuntu, (even with the built-in nouveau driver).

Comment: Maybe you should try a newer version with a newer kernel and newer hardware drivers. You can try Ubuntu 19.10 or the developing version 'Focal Fossa' to become Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in April. [Download from this link](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/206401/downloads)

Comment: I'll try to find out what "AHCI" might mean in the BIOS.  In the meantime, I'll try version 19.10.  Thank you for your responses

Comment: My history with Linux in the past 3 days:
--2 versions of Mint (Cinnamon and Mate) were unstable no matter how they were installed, and crash within minutes of reaching the desktop.  
--2 Versions of Ubuntu (18.04.3 and 19.10) won’t even reach a desktop.  They just go to a black screen and reboot the computer.  --PCLinux reached a desktop but then was more of the same, no matter which install option I used.  Apparently there are conflicts with Linux and my computer, including, but not limited to, the BIOS, and/or drivers. At this point, I’m not pursuing Linux further.